# boldsymbol doesn't work with ASME template

Tags: amsmath, boldsymbol

I am using the ASME paper template http://iel.ucdavis.edu/code/ASME/, I am trying to use `\boldsymbol{\theta}` from `\usepackage{amsmath}` but it doesn't work, only shows a regular `\theta`.  Does anyone know how to make it work?  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try `bm` package and the command `\bm{\theta}` ... `\boldsymbol` doesn's work on Greek characters ... `bm` package is used in such cases.

Comment: `\boldsymbol` should work fine for Greek characters, if you load a font that comes with a bold version.

Comment: Thanks for koleygr's suggestion, the `bm` package works perfectly with the asme template.

Comment: The classes do `\RequirePackage{times,mathptm}` and both packages have been obsolete and deprecated for 25 years. No reasonable bold math can be obtained with them. Yes, `\bm{\theta}` yields a not so bad output, but try with other letters and you'll see why it is not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template you link loads the obsolete `mathptmx` package.  The simplest solution is probably to load [`bm`](//ctan.org/pkg/bm) (which will alias `\boldsymbol` to `\bm`).  **ETA:** As @egreg warns, `bm` with `mathptmx` breaks on some installations, but you might not have an alternative if the publisher does not allow you to change the font.

You could also load `newtxmath` for a math font based on Times that does come in bold, but it is likely that the publisher won’t want you to do this.

Comment: I would definitely not use `\bm` with `mathptmx`. I mean, unless you find output such as in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx3Yy.png) acceptable. I don't.

Comment: @egreg I wouldn’t use `mathptmx` by choice, ever—the package description itself warns that it’s obsolete! Upgrading to `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` solves rhe problem. Assuming, however, that someone is not allowed to change the fonts, what would you recommend?

Comment: @egreg Good point. Added a note.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you try the newer ASME conference paper template, https://ctan.org/pkg/asmeconf, which is based on the modern `newtx` fonts and which will support `\boldsymbol{\theta}` and many other math characters.